# GitHub "compare branches" page not showing recent change although it's visible in the individual branch

Tags: caching, github

I made a change in `branch2` on my local machine which had been brnched off of `branch1` and pushed it (`branch2`) to the remote on GitHub. Then, I merged `branch2` into `branch1` so now both branches have the change. Finally, I pushed `branch1` to the remote as well. This can be summarized as:

```
(branch1) $ git checkout branch2
## make change1
(branch2) $ git commit -m foo
(branch2) $ git push

(branch2) $ git checkout branch1
(branch1) $ git merge branch2
(branch1) $ git push
```

Now, on GitHub, both branches have the change shown. I then made another change to `branch2`, pushed it and went to GitHub to open a new pull request of `branch2` against `branch1`. The problem is that the change I had originally pushed (`change1`) is not shown in `branch1` in the comparison, only on `branch2`.

If I open `branch1` and browse to the file in question, `change1` is there. So I assume I don't see it in the pull request comparison page because of some sort of caching. Is there any way I can force GitHub to refresh its cache and show the change? Reloading the pull request page, or closing and recreating the pull request makes no difference. It has now been a couple of hours so it isn't a question of just waiting a few seconds either.

How can I force GitHub to refresh the cached version of the file from `branch1` so it reflects the current state of the branch?

Comment: It should not be there. `change1` is already included in `branch1`.
So why would you see it in comparison between `branch1` and `branch2`?

Comment: I mean it is shown as a new change; as a difference between `branch1` and `branch2`.